# Which network protocols do trading systems use for speed?

Tags: software

Someone told me that trading systems are very time-dependent and they must use network protocols that ensure speed.

Which network protocols do they use to ensure fast transmissions?

What’s an example of such a system?

Thank you

Comment: My understanding is that it is not a special protocol, but the high speed is achieved through special hardware and special driver software that handles the messages that are received/sent as efficiently as possible, plus location of the computer electrically close to the exchange. And maybe other tricks that you and I don't know ;)

Comment: Can you provide any example of such a financial system? Are we talking like a cryptocurrency exchange or something? I’m trying to learn about network protocols with enforced speed. Thanks very much

Comment: I was thinking of for example high speed futures trading on the Chicago Merc (which some friends of mine are or were involved with) or HFT stock trading. Regrettably I don't know anything about crypto exchanges.

Comment: Awesome, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Guessing from your post that you're asking about the transport layer. Most financial firms prefer to use raw UDP for transport when they're colocated in the same data center. Aeron is another one that has been gaining some steam.

As for the presentation layer, ITCH and SBE are fairly popular these days between markets and participants, however firms might just write their own proprietary wire protocol when they're just communicating between internal systems.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the leads